# TikZ-UML: How to shrink lost space within classes?

Tags: tikz-uml

I am using TikZ-UML to illustrate some concepts in a scientific paper. 
It does the job pretty well, but I have some space problems (as in all scientific papers, there is page limit). I already managed to shrink my figures by position in the concept properly, but there is a lot of lost space within the objects.

[image: typical example where space is lost in classes]

Consider the vertical space between the name of the objects in the figure, and the lines. There is something like 4 pt between the top of "A" and the line above it, for instance, and 6 pt below "A" as well.

Is there a way to control this space, in order to further shrink my figures?

Here is a minimal example of an object model made using `tikz-uml`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlsimpleclass{A}
\umlsimpleclass[x=2]{B}
\umlassoc{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

By reading `tikzuml.sty`, I've seen a line:

```
\tikzstyle{tikzuml simpleclass style}=[rectangle, minimum height=2em, node distance=2em]%
```

I set the minimum height to 1em. This changes the lost space above "A" and "B", but not below

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your request.

Comment: Do you mean how to reduce the size of the blocks A, B, C? For instance you could use `\node [block, minimum size=2mm] (Ablock) {A};`.

Comment: This means not using the tikZ-uml package; I was hoping to keep on using it actually. I was wondering how to tell tikz-uml to draw a smaller box around A for instance

Comment: for instance, the object "A" is drawn using the primitive

\umlsimpleclass{A}

and it notably offers some support for routing the links between the boxes

Comment: Please do make it a habit to include complete code examples when asking questions. In some cases it's entirely necessary to be able to solve a problem, and in cases like this it's just so much nicer to not have to make up a complete example from scratch. (I usually want and need to actually test code before posting.)

Comment: Here is a minimal example of an object model made using tikz-uml: 

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlsimpleclass{A}
\umlsimpleclass[x=2]{B}
\umlassoc{A}{B}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

By eeading tikzuml.sty, I'v sees a line: 

\tikzstyle{tikzuml simpleclass style}=[rectangle, minimum height=2em, node distance=2em]%

I' set the minimum height to 1em. This changes the lost space above "A" and "B", but not below

Comment: Comments are the wrong place for blocks of code, there is an *edit* link just above the comments, so you can add the code to your question. After pasting it in, select it and hit Ctrl + K to highlight it properly as code.

Answer (score 4):

There two or three things to modify for the nodes in question. (`\umlclass` in the end just makes a `\node`.) First, the `minimum height`, which is set to `2em` by `tikz-uml`, and second the `inner ysep`, which determines the vertical distance from the node content to the node border.

So for example, if you do

```
\umlsimpleclass[x=2,minimum height=0pt,inner ysep=0pt]{A}
```

you get the output on the right, while the default is on the left:

[image: simpleclass with less vertical space]

There is still some space because the content is set in a `tabular`, i.e. you have a situation like

```
\node [inner ysep=0pt,draw] {\begin{tabular}{c}A\end{tabular}};
```

Another parameter to play with is `text depth`. Be aware of letters with descenders though (like y, g, j), if the `text depth` is too small, the letter might stick out of the node.

You can modify the styles `tikzuml simpleclass style` and `tikzuml class style` with e.g.

```
\tikzset{
  tikzuml class style/.append style={minimum height=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=2pt}
}
```

or make your own style that you add to the nodes where you want it.

Left is default, middle is modifying `tikz-uml` styles, right is with custom styles. They appear in that order in the code below.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzset{
  reduce height/.style={
    minimum height=0pt,
    inner ysep=#1,
    text depth=2pt
  },
  reduce height/.default={0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\umlsimpleclass[x=-2]{Ay}
\umlclass[x=-2,y=-2]{B}{foo}{barg}
\umlclass[x=-2,y=-4]{B}{}{}

\begin{scope}[
  % instead of a scope environment, you can add these style modifications
  % in the options to a tikzpicture, or in \tikzset{} in the preamble
  tikzuml simpleclass style/.append style={minimum height=0pt,inner sep=0pt},
  tikzuml class style/.append style={minimum height=0pt,inner sep=0pt},
]
\umlsimpleclass{Ay}
\umlclass[y=-2]{B}{foo}{barg}
\umlclass[y=-4]{B}{}{}
\end{scope}

\umlsimpleclass[x=2,reduce height]{Ay}
\umlclass[y=-2,x=2,reduce height=1pt]{B}{foo}{barg}
\umlclass[y=-4,x=2,reduce height]{B}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```