# Shrinking UML Components

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

In order to fit an UML diagram made with TiKZ-UML ([https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/)) into a beamer slide, I am currently trying to shrink the body part of the components. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to do so.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}        
        
\usepackage{parts/umldocument}
\usepackage{parts/umlmultidocument}
\usepackage{parts/umlcomponent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example UML Components}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  
  \begin{umlcomponent}{A}
   \hspace{-1cm}
  \end{umlcomponent}  
  
  \umlbasiccomponent[x=3, minimum height=0pt] {B} 
  
  \umlbasiccomponent[x=6, inner ysep=0pt] {C} 
  
  \umlbasiccomponent[x=9, outer ysep=0pt] {D} 
  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but this only creates the following output:

[image: Four Components Without Reduced Size (except C, which is broken)]

While setting `inner ysep=0pt` (from [TikZ-UML: How to shrink lost space within classes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401403/tikz-uml-how-to-shrink-lost-space-within-classes)) reduces the size, it reduces the size of the overall component in a way that breaks its appearance. It is also possible to set `inner ysep=-2pt`, which further reduces the body, but it also reduces the header size.

Also adding

```
\tikzset{
  tikzuml component style/.append style={minimum height=0pt,inner ysep=0pt,text depth=2pt}
}
```

has no effect.

Has anybody an idea how to shrink the size of the body of an tikz-uml component, without breaking its header part?

Answer (score 1):

I came up myself with one intermediary solution: In `tikz-uml.sty`, one can adjust the line 4754 from

```
  \node[inner sep=2ex, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, fit = \csname tikzumlComponentFit\tikzumlComponent@parent @@\tikzumlComponent@fitname\endcsname] (\tikzumlComponent@nodeName-body) {};%
```

to

```
  \node[inner sep=0ex, font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, fit = \csname tikzumlComponentFit\tikzumlComponent@parent @@\tikzumlComponent@fitname\endcsname] (\tikzumlComponent@nodeName-body) {};%
```

Thereby, the spacing is reduced.

This will affect **all** components in the picture (and the whole presentation), therefore a solution achieving to set the parameter from the outside would be much nicer.

Comment: If you're already editing the sty file you could say `\node[every whatever node/.try, …` and then use that style to set it from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, could you further specify the solution? My workaround solution is editing https://github.com/emanuelenardi/latex-packages/blob/163b733047c2824b8d802a460dbff59b75d8a095/tikz-uml/tikz-uml.sty#L4754, but I do not see which `whatever node` to edit (using `tikzuml component style` like in the question did not work).

Comment: You could just add an empty style to every `\node` at the end of the options and then you can (re)define that style outside and then TikZ would pick it up. If you use a key in the `/tikzuml/component` namespace you can define it in the optional argument of the `umlcomponent` environment and TikZ would pick it up. Say you change line 4754 so that it reads `\node[…, /tikzuml/component/foo/.try] …;` you should then be able to use `\begin{umlcomponent}[foo/.style={fill=green}]`. Or `\pgfqkeys{/tikzuml/component/foo/.style=…}` for a global approach. (Yes, I'd rewrite the class.)